# There is an error stating that "exit status 1 expected unqualified-id before 'if'. This project is used to turn on/off LED and magnetic door

Tags: arduino-uno

```cpp
* /
#define CUSTOM_SETTINGS
#define INCLUDE_KEYPAD_SHIELD

/* Include 1Sheeld library. */
#include <OneSheeld.h>

/* Define an iterator. */
int iterations = 0;

/* A name for the LockPin on pin D2. */
int lockPin = 2;
int ledRed = A5;
int ledGreen = A4;

/* A name for the switch led on pin D5. */
const int lampuPin = 5;
const int ledlampu = A0;

// variables will change:
int buttonState = 0; // variable for reading the pushbutton status
int stateBefore = 0;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

void setup() {
  /* Start communication. */
  OneSheeld.begin();
  /* Set the LED & LOCK as output. */
  pinMode(lockPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledRed, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledGreen, OUTPUT);
  /* Set the LampuPin pin as output. */
  pinMode(lampuPin, INPUT);
  /* Set the LED pin as output. */
  pinMode(ledlampu, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  //======Lampu Rumah=======
  // read the state of the pushbutton value:
  buttonState = digitalRead(lampuPin);
  if (buttonState != stateBefore) {
    if (buttonState == HIGH and i == 0) {
      digitalWrite (ledlampu, HIGH);
      j = 1;
    } else if (buttonState == LOW and j == 1) {
      i = 1;
    } else if (buttonState == HIGH and i == 1) {
      digitalWrite (ledlampu, LOW);
      j = 0;
    } else if (buttonState == LOW and j == 0) {
      i = 0;
    }
  }
  stateBefore = buttonState;
}

//======Pintu Hadapan Rumah=======
/* Check if "1" is pressed, iterate one time. */
if (iterations == 0 && isOnePressed()) {
  iterations++;
} else if (iterations == 1 && isTwoPressed()) {
  /* Check if "2" is pressed, iterate one time. */
  iterations++;
} else if (iterations == 2 && isThreePressed()) {
  /* Check if "3" is pressed, iterate one time. */
  iterations++;
} else if (iterations == 3 && isFourPressed()) {
  /* Check if "4" is pressed, iterate one time. */
  iterations++;
} else if (isOtherButtonPressed()) {
  /* Check if any other button is pressed, reset iterations. */
  iterations = 0;
}
if (iterations == 4) {
  /* Check if the number of iterations is 4, blink the LED. */
  digitalWrite(lockPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledGreen, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledRed, LOW);
  OneSheeld.delay(6000);
  digitalWrite(lockPin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledRed, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledGreen, LOW);
  OneSheeld.delay(1000);
  /* Reset the iterator. */
  iterations = 0;
}

/* Helper functions check if a certain button is pressed by checking its row and column. */

boolean isOnePressed() {
  return Keypad.isRowPressed(0) && Keypad.isColumnPressed(0);
}

boolean isTwoPressed() {
  return Keypad.isRowPressed(0) && Keypad.isColumnPressed(1);
}

boolean isThreePressed() {
  return Keypad.isRowPressed(0) && Keypad.isColumnPressed(2);
}

boolean isFourPressed() {
  return Keypad.isRowPressed(1) && Keypad.isColumnPressed(0);
}

boolean isOtherButtonPressed() {
  return ((Keypad.isAnyColumnPressed() || Keypad.isAnyColumnPressed()) && !isOnePressed() && !isTwoPressed() && !isThreePressed() && !isFourPressed());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You got an extra closing brace after this line.

```
stateBefore = buttonState;
}
```

It ends the loop function so the next if is outside any function and illegal.  Hit Control-T in the IDE to auto-format the code and it will line up the indention and that will help you spot these sorts of errors.